# How to define a object value using a specific key when returning an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I need to change the value of a specific key when returning an object. I don't know if there is a way to do this.

Is hard to tell exacty what I need, but in the **code below** is easy to get:

```
return {
  ...state,
  cart: [
     ...state.cart,
     state.cart[itemIndex]: {  // <- This is what I want, but this way doesn't work
       {
         productId: action.product.productId,
         quantity: action.quantity
       },
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show the action payload that you're passing to your reducer and the sample of your state that you attempt to modify.

Comment: `[state.cart[itemIndex]]: {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to replace an item in an array, you'll need to use array methods to get to the right index.

You can use `Array.map()` to set the item at the requested index:

```
return {
  ...state,
  cart: state.cart.map((item, index) => 
    index !== itemIndex ? item : {
      productId: action.product.productId,
      quantity: action.quantity
    }
  )
}
```

Or use `Array.slice()` with array spread:

```
return {
  ...state,
  cart: [
    state.cart.slice(0, itemIndex),
    {
      productId: action.product.productId,
      quantity: action.quantity
    }
    state.cart.slice(itemIndex + 1),
  ]
}
```

A shorter option would be to clone the array, and just replace the item in the requested index:

```
const updatedCart = [...state.cart]
updatedCart[itemIndex] = {
  productId: action.product.productId,
  quantity: action.quantity
}

return {
  ...state,
  cart: updatedCart
}
```

Using [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction):

```
import produce from 'immer'

return produce(state, draftState => {
  draftState.cart[itemIndex] = {
    productId: action.product.productId,
    quantity: action.quantity
  }
})
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the way that I want doesn't exists?

Comment: The shorter option is great, thanks! I don't know why the heck I didn't think this way xD

Comment: Nope. Array spread just shallow clones the entire array to a new one. Everything you add after the spread would be last. In addition, the syntax [key]: value doesn't work with arrays.

Comment: You should also checkout immer - it does the immutable heavy lifting for you.